# Is there a case sensitive method to filter columns in a dataframe by header?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and different headers.
I want to filter the dataframe to keep only the columns that start with the letter I. Some of my column headers have the letter i but start with a different letter.

Is there a way to do this?
I tried using df.filter but for some reason, it's not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.filter` with the `regex` parameter:

```
df.filter(regex=r'(?i)^i')
```

this will return columns starting with `I` ignoring the case.
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WuWO3f/14)

Example below:

Lets consider the input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,(5,4)),
      columns=['itest','Itest','another','anothericol'])
```

---

```
print(df)

   itest  Itest  another  anothericol
0      1      4       14           17
1     17     10       14            1
2     16     18       10            7
3     10     12       17           14
4      6     15       17           19
```

---

With `df.filter`

```
print(df.filter(regex=r'(?i)^i'))

   itest  Itest
0      1      4
1     17     10
2     16     18
3     10     12
4      6     15
```

Comment: you could be verbose and pass a list comprehension to `loc` ``df.loc[:, [col.startswith("I") for col in df]]``. could be handy for folks that are not regex brave. Also, I may be wrong, but it seems the OP wants something that is case sensitvie and will filter for only capital `I`

Comment: @sammywemmy one can convert to lower and use startswith with small case 'i'. However looks like this has been already answered hence I will be editing this to be a community wiki. Also I think we can do df.columns.str.startswith(('i','I')) as str.startswith takes a tuple, and pass into loc.

Comment: yea. True. The tuple part is a good one as well.